# Is there a way to automate SEO checks?

Tags: build, jenkins, seo, gruntjs, release

We have struggled with junior staff members allowing code to get to production without being adequately checked for SEO.

Are there any good options to add some checks to a build process? We're already using Grunt and Jenkins so ideally we would be able to add a task as a last line of defence in our build process. Are there any libraries that could help?

Comment: What kind of checks are you expecting?

Comment: Essentially, as much of the following that is feasible to automate https://github.com/tutsplus/SEO-Checklist-for-Web-Designers/blob/master/seo_checklist.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there aren't any tools available to run this in a build context such as Grunt. The only thing that I've come across in a quick npm search is [webcheck](https://npmjs.org/package/webcheck), a crawler that can register various middleware and generate a JSON report for you. I'm not aware of any grunt wrapper for this module, but if you find it fits your needs then it might be worth a shot. It looks like the `seo` reporter in that module reports on keywords which is pretty interesting.

If you decide to write your own module, one of webcheck's dependencies is [crawl](https://npmjs.org/package/crawl), which could help you validate pages on your own site against some of those rules. The ones that I would aim for are:

- Page access - Keep an index of pages you expect to hit and make sure they don't 404.
- Page blocking - Make sure that unlisted pages have `nofollow` on them.
- Pagination - Checking for `rel="prev"` is trivial.
- Page speed - Grunt plugin already for this - https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-pagespeed
- Duplicate content issues (not sure exactly how you'd handle this one though, would be interesting to see) - maybe using https://npmjs.org/package/diff
- www or non-www - Make sure you use www.example.com instead of example.com and be consistent
- Descriptive URLs - check them against keywords in title/h1 tags?
- Impose 70 character limit on titles
- Content length - make sure your articles aren't spammy 50 word posts
- Alt tag on images - use [HTMLHint](https://github.com/yaniswang/HTMLHint/wiki/Rules) (there is also grunt-htmlhint)

I'd hope that you are already using a sitemap generator of some kind, either with something like WordPress which will do it automatically, or as part of your build. If not you can use this one: https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-sitemap

Would really like to see something like this, could be a fun project if you've got some spare time for it. :-)